# No puede abrir la link en menu

Tags: jquery, html

al final cuando click no puede abrir un link (`<a href="www.google.com">`)

```js
$('.menu-lateral .sub-menu').hide();
 
$('.menu-lateral li a').click(function(){
event.preventDefault();
$(this).siblings('.sub-menu').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-lateral">

    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">

            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">

                    <li><a href="#">Sub sub Menu 3</a>

                        <ul class="sub-menu">

                            <li><a target="_blank" href="www.google.com">Titulo no puede abrir link :( </a></li>

                        </ul>

                    </li>

                </ul>

            </li>

        </ul>

    </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero:

- event.preventDefault(); lo que hace es evitar que haga la accion que normalmente hace, para reemplazarla por la del script. Por lo tanto borra esa linea
- La url debe ser así: href="http://www.google.com" o sino lo buscaras dentro de tu dominio.

Te dejo tu código modificado:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-lateral">

    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">

            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">

                    <li><a href="#">Sub sub Menu 3</a>

                        <ul class="sub-menu">

                            <li><a  href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Titulo</a></li>

                        </ul>

                    </li>

                </ul>

            </li>

        </ul>

    </li>

</ul>

<script>
$('.menu-lateral .sub-menu').hide();
 
$('.menu-lateral li a').click(function(){

$(this).siblings('.sub-menu').slideToggle('slow');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias , entendido.

Comment: Por nada. Saludos desde Paraguay

Answer (score 3):

Esto ocurre porque tu selector es muy genérico. Al hacer:

```
$('.menu-lateral li a').click(function(){......
```

estás seleccionando todos los enlaces (`a`), que estén dentro de un `li` dentro del `.menu-lateral`. Sin especificar a qué nivel. Eso hace que se aplica a todos los enlaces dentro del `li`. Y cómo tienes un `event.preventDefault()` no se ejecutará la acción del enlace.

Por ejemplo, tu estructura es algo así:

```
ul.menu-lateral
   li
       a   <------------- el selector afectará a este link
       ul
           li
                a  <----- y también a éste
```

Para que haga lo que buscas, deberías hacer el selector más específico, usando `>` que significa que será descendiente directo. En este caso, el selector que quieres usar sería así:

```
$('.menu-lateral > li > a').click(function(){
```

Y con tu estructura se seleccionaría asi:

```
ul.menu-lateral
   li
       a   <------------- el selector afectará a este link y sólo a éste
       ul
           li
                a
```

---

Actualización: como tu menú tiene subniveles, el selector que sugiero arriba no funcionará correctamente. Lo que puedes hacer es cromprobar si el enlace pulsado es un nodo hoja (no tiene más subniveles), y si no lo es, ejecutar el código. De este modo si es nodo hoja, se ejecutará irá al `href` normalmente.

Para comprobar si tiene submenús, deberías comprobar si alguno de sus hermanos tiene la clase "sub-menu" usando `.siblings(".sub-menu")`.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo (nota que he quitado el `target="_blank"` y corregido la URL... y aún así no funcionará por motivos de seguridad):

```js
$('.menu-lateral .sub-menu').hide();

$('.menu-lateral li a').click(function(event){
  if ($(this).siblings(".sub-menu").length > 0) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').slideToggle('slow');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-lateral">
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Sub sub Menu 3</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Titulo no puede abrir link :( </a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: buen ejemplo, Gracias por explicarme.

Comment: lo del selector no le perjudicara porque intentara abrir un nuevo submenu pero que no existe. con que quite el event.prevent y actualice el link ya le va a funcionar

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta de que tu ejemplo tiene dos niveles de menú. El selector no sería exactamente igual al que te he puesto. Podrías hacer algo como `$('.menu-lateral > li > a, .menu-lateral > li > ul  > li > a').click(function(){ .... ` pero podría afectar negativamente si hay menús sin tercer nivel

Comment: @AlexisGranja Sí y no. Si el menú no está en la parte superior de la página sí que afectará porque al tener `href="#"` el scroll se desplazará a la parte superior de la pantalla (otra historia sería si tuviera `href="javascript:void(0)"`)

Comment: Si asi mismo, pero en éste caso no le afecta, si en todo caso si no estará al inicio pues le agrega href="javascript:void(0)" o añade una clase y la usa

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente porque estas evitando que lo haga

`event.preventDefault();`

a esa última liga puedes colocarle una clase

`<a class="liga" target="_blank" href="www.google.com">Titulo no puede abrir link :( </a>`

y en el js puedes hacer

```
if(!this.hasClass('liga'))
    event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">Titulo SÍ puede abrir link :) </a></li>
```

Y eliminas esto: `event.preventDefault();`